# Store looped output in a variable

Tags: php

I have this PHP which outputs a list of managers and underneath that their employees & requests.

This works great right now - however, I'd like to store all the HTML in a variable for each manager instead of outputting it on the page. How do I achieve this?

```
<?php 

while($row = $resultt->fetch_assoc())  {
    $arr = explode("@", $row['email'], 2);
    $first = $arr[0];
    $first = str_replace('.','-',$first);
    $email = $row['email'];
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE manager_email LIKE '%".$email."%'";
    $resultt2 = $con->query($sql2);

    echo '<table class="'.$first.'">';

    $i++;

    while($row2 = $resultt2->fetch_assoc())  {

        echo '<tr><td>'.$row2['email'].':</td>';
        $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM requests WHERE submitted_by = '".$row2['email']."'";
        $resultt3 = $con->query($sql3);
        $count = 0;
        while($row3 = $resultt3->fetch_assoc())  {
            $count++;               
        }
        echo '<td>'.$count.'</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: `This works great right now` even wit the syntax error in `echo '<tr><td>.$row2['email'].':</td>';`?

Comment: Good spot! I was tidying it for SO and missed a bit :-)

Comment: Please [read this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php). Thanks.

Comment: Why would you store it?? For other requests ?  If so, PHP doesn't support state sharing between requests, so you could persist this state somewhere externally, either in database, redis, or memcached. If for the same request, just make a variable like `$grandResult` or something, then use `$grandResult .= ` instead of echo.     Or setting the output buffer not to output to screen then reading from it after end, http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: Also try to see something like that: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php

Comment: side note: executing queries in a loop or even in a loop within another loop isn't that good for performance, isn't it? Better one nice SQL query for everything :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = '';
while($row = $resultt->fetch_assoc())  {
    $arr = explode("@", $row['email'], 2);
    $first = $arr[0];
    $first = str_replace('.','-',$first);
    $email = $row['email'];
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE manager_email LIKE '%".$email."%'";
    $resultt2 = $con->query($sql2);

    $output .=  '<table class="'.$first.'">';

    $i++;

    while($row2 = $resultt2->fetch_assoc())  {

        $output .=  '<tr><td>'.$row2['email'].':</td>';
        $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM requests WHERE submitted_by = '".$row2['email']."'";
        $resultt3 = $con->query($sql3);
        $count = 0;
        while($row3 = $resultt3->fetch_assoc())  {
            $count++;               
        }
        $output .=  '<td>'.$count.'</td></tr>';
    }
    $output .=  '</table>';
}

echo $output;
```

all output now store in **$output**

Comment: Many thanks, @zeshan - apologies for delay. Will test this right now.

Comment: Hi - I've tried this but it keeps adding the results to output. So the first set of managers loop then that adds to the second set and third and so on. So by the end all managers, employees are listed in one giant table at the end.